# Topology of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions, event-horizon, singularities

How many dimensions are theorized for a black hole, in view of the fact that black holes are not observed directly.

Comment: By "topography" do you mean *topology*?

Comment: Thank you Ocelo7; as I am a physics neophyte, whichever applies contextually correctly has my vote!

Comment: Your second question is [answered here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/what-is-a-black-hole).

Comment: That answer is probably too technical for this context.

Comment: There are many black hole solutions in a variety of dimensions. You'll have to improve your question.

Comment: Does this refer to the event horizon? The singularity?